# Long polling ajax issue

Tags: ajax, long-polling

I have set up a polling script which basically checks the notification_queue if any new notifications are available. If they are it will display them and delete the notification from the queue.

I'm using firebug and when I reload the page the previous poll stays open and a new one is created.

```
        function poll(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 30000,

            success: function(data){
               $.gritter.add({

                    title: 'This is a regular notice!',

                    text: data.message,

                    image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',

                    sticky: false,

                    time: ''
               });
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("OMG ERROR");
            }
        });
    };
    poll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the reason is that you pass poll as the complete function, effectively creating a non-terminating or cascading recursion (don't know if that is the proper term from programming 101 ...)

Comment: I've only just started working with polling today but isnt that the idea to keep the poll going. So if another notification gets added the user is told?

Comment: that is the idea of polling, but in your approach complete is part of poll itself, so if you call yourself from yourself, that's a recursion.

You can try it with an anonymous function

   $.ajax({
    complete: function(){
     poll();
    },
    ....
    })

Comment: You was correct. I have taken away the;
complete: poll

and added poll(); within the success area and it seems to be alright.

Thanks you for your help.